# node value in domdocument is print as html source and not excuted

Tags: php, domdocument

here is my code

```
    $link = "<a class=\"openevent\" href=\"$finalUrl\" target=\"_blank\">Open Event</a>";
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    if ($span->getAttribute('class') == 'category') {
        $span->nodeValue .= $link;
    }
}
```

the problem here is that $link will something like this

```
<a class="openevent" href="http://www.domain.com/Free-Live-Streaming-Video-Online-Hockey-NHL-Pre-season-Buffalo-Sabres-Montreal-Canadiens-170647.html" target="_blank">Open Event</a>
```

with my current code the above html code appear in the browser as is and not executed to be as [Open Event](http://www.domain.com/Free-Live-Streaming-Video-Online-Hockey-NHL-Pre-season-Buffalo-Sabres-Montreal-Canadiens-170647.html) 
so what is wrong with my coding

Answer (score 0):

Use [createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and [appendChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to add an element to each span, rather than setting nodeValue.